# Issue in displaying .emf files in SharePoint Online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-migration

We are using Sharepoint Online 2013.
We have migrated Lotus Notes documents using Dell Migrator for Notes to SharePoint.

The `.emf` files are shown as a cross.
I browsed the internet to check if SharePoint supports such type of files. I found out it does support.

What can be the problem?
Do I need to enable any settings?

Answer (score 0):

This page might describe the issue you are having: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/Feedback+Print?OpenForm&ParentUNID=B4279D5083AE2E6D85257632004CC21A

The Dell Migrator for Notes to SharePoint may have stored the file in an associated _attachments library, instead of in the target migration library.  Did your migration job create one of those directories alongside the main .emf files?